# How to separate functions accessing Parse.com into a separate class?

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, pfquery

I have this function (using this function as example only, question is about all parse accesses) below that I need to call from several different `UIViewController` classes.

I was hoping to put this function in a separate class that I can instantiate in multiple `UIViewController` classes and call this function.

Since the `saveInBackgroundWithBlock` is an asynchronous process, how can I return the `scoreAgain` object back to the UIViewController class.

Is this even possible?

```
var query = PFQuery(className: "GameScore")
query.getObjectInBackgroundWithId(gameScore.objectId) {
    (scoreAgain: PFObject!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
    if !error {
       NSLog("%@", scoreAgain.objectForKey("playerName") as NSString)
    } else {
    NSLog("%@", error)
    }
}
```

The goal here is to separate the cloud back end accesses into separate classes because if I change my backend from `Parse.com` to something else in the future, I dont have to touch my `UIViewController` classes but only change the Helper classes.

Comment: I wouldn't have this query in my viewController as well I would have it in a class responsible for the score, the only think the viewController would do would be call giveScore, so in the future if you decide to stop use parse you don't need to touch the views just the models. But that's just my opinion

Comment: yes exactly that's the question. How to return a value from a separate class since `getObjectInBackgroundWithId` is asynchronous so can take a lot of time. How will the `UIViewController` know when the `getObjectInBackgroundWithId` is complete and has returned a value.

Comment: There are many ways, you can set observer in the variable you are changing, or you can set notifications for when the update is finished, or you can use protocols. In the example I gave to you I would use protocol I would call getScore and keep doing whatever I need to do and when the result was back it would call my protocol that would display the score.